# Redirect page to root but keep the parameters in URL

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

*I have a rather complex problem (for me), which is why i need to turn to you guys :) Always heave been a great and fast ressource for help.*

**Background:**
I have a website where the homepage is one big draggable screen (www.example.com/) where all the subpages are teasered. If you click on a Teaser (www.example.com/pages/page1) a jquery lightbox with iframe will open and present that page. That works great.

**Problem:**
Problem is, as always have been with iframes, if someone goes to the subpage directly (www.example.com/pages/page1), maybe via an indexed google search, he will not see the iframe and the big draggable screen behind it.

**Question:**
i'd need a script which, before anything happens, redirects an URL with more parts then root to the root page and append the parts as a different query, so i could read them out via javascript or something and trigger the iframelightbox per hand.

**Approach:**
so

```
www.example.com/pages/page1
```

needs to become

```
www.example.com?vars=/pages/page1
```

or something appropriate.

i think this is possible using mod_rewrite in my htaccess but i dont know how.

I hope this it understandable in some way :) i tried my best.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?vars=$1
```

Should do the trick.

Don't put an * instead of + or you may end in infinite loop.

Comment: ok i used it bu got weird result. do i still need a RewriteCond?
my code now looks like this
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?vars=$1`

Comment: sorry for the messy markup, i dont know how to put line breaks in comments.

Comment: you can't keep the RewriteCond + RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  since it would negate the behaviour you need, unless the pages you are asking are in fact `pages/page1` on your filesystem. But else, it will say : not a directory I rewrite to index.php and then skip the last RewriteRule.

Comment: sorry for not following up anymore, your Rule kinda work, but then a thousand new problems opened up and i dropped the issue for now. thanks anyway for helping :) i upvoted you anyway, because i think it would be the right way.